# Sending compressed data in from as3 to node.js express

Tags: node.js, actionscript-3, express, gzip, zlib

I'm trying to send a compressed string to a node.js express server from Flash AS3. In AS3 I have something like this:

```
// AS3 Code
function save(data:ByteArray, theURL:String, compress:Boolean):void {

if (compress == true)
{
    data.compress();
}


try
{
    var request:URLRequest=new URLRequest(theURL);
    request.data= data;
    request.method=URLRequestMethod.POST;
    request.contentType = "application/octet-stream";               

    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();             
    loader.load(request);           
}
catch (ex)
{

}

}
```

Testing it like this:

```
save("This is a test string", "http://example.com/flash/", true);
```

Node Code

```
app.post('/flash/', bodyParser.raw({limit: '5mb'}), function(req,res){

    console.log(req.body);
    zlib.gunzip(req.body, function(err, unzipped_body){
            if (!err)
            {
                console.log(unzipped_body);
            }
            console.log(err);
        });

    });
```

req.body ends up having a byte buffer in it but when I try to zlib.gunzip I get an incorrect header check.

```
<Buffer 78 da 0b c9 c8 2c 56 00 a2 dc 4a 85 94 c4 92 44 00 2a 56 05 55>
x?♂??,V ??J??ED *V♣U
{ [Error: incorrect header check] errno: -3, code: 'Z_DATA_ERROR' }
```

If I don't do the data.compress() in as3 then req.body in Node shows the original string. What am I not understanding about the zlib compression, or node, or whatever? :)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it should be zlib.unzip and not zlib.gunzip. I suppose the as3 compress() function isn't "gzip" format but rather "zlib" format?

Comment: That's what the [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html#compress()) says. The default algorithm is `zlib`, but you can also explicitly specify `deflate` or `lzma`.